# next cannot be resolved to a value or field in java

Tags: java, recursion, circular-list

I have this question:

Write a recursive java function that counts the number of nodes in a circularly 
linked list.

Here is the method/function:

```
public int countNodes(Node node){

    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
            return 1+countNodes(node.next);
    }
}
```

I get an error in the line 
return 1+countNodes(node.next); 
which says that: next cannot be resolved to a value or field in java

What am I supposed to do to fix this error?

Comment: What is `next` meant to be? Where is it defined/declared?

Comment: It is meant to be the next node to be accessed. I have to define it?

Comment: Likely you don't have next defined in `Node` or it's not visible from your method.

Comment: How and as what type do I define next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Node class should be like this:

```
public class Node {

    private Node next;

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    //setter and other stuff


}
```

and you have to call node.getNext()

```
 return 1+countNodes(node.getNext());
```

Don't forget that Java is a object oriented language.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code stands, you are trying to access a non-existent field called "next" in Node. Either add that field (if Node is a class you created), or did you mean to call a method called next? If so, do `node.next()`